# Mule ESB can be deployed in Application Server

Tags: esb, mule

Can I deploy Mule on any of the application server. If so how do we deploy the Mule examples.

I have configured my eclipse to run JBoss and Mule Flows dont get deployed in the JBOss server. The syncronisation gives error(null pointer).

But when I run as Mule Application it runs fine but starts Mule Server.

How does Mule deployed in the production? Do we need Mule server in production working along with the application Server?

Can we package all the application in one(ESB + application) and deploy it in the application server.

Answer (score 4):

You have the choice regarding production deployments of Mule:

- Use Mule standalone as your first choice, as it comes packed with all modules/transport, is production grade (control scripts...) and supports hot application reloads.
- If your deployment environment forces you to deploy on application servers (like JBoss), [package your Mule application as a web application](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Embedding+Mule+in+a+Java+Application+or+Webapp#EmbeddingMuleinaJavaApplicationorWebapp-EmbeddingMuleinaWebapp) (WAR).

If you decide to package your Mule application as a WAR, I strongly suggest you use Maven to do so, as they each Mule module/transport require numerous dependencies. Dealing with this by hand would be insane.

Also be sure to use [Servlet inbound endpoints](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Servlet+Transport+Reference) instead of HTTP inbound endpoints otherwise Mule will open another HTTP server inside the web container. You want Mule to use the servlet container for its inbound HTTP requests.

Comment: I would like to know more about how to deploy the project as a WAR. I am not able to see documentation around the same.Servlet Inbound endpoint is very good point, probably i would not have found in documention if not told. I am currently using Eclipse plugin to model my flows. can i export the same as WAR. Can i have a sample build file or maven project build which can make the WAR. I am not able to relate the deployment as there is not WEB-INF and the servlet or jsp and the relative path. Direct me to a link which is giving examples. Thank you for helping. Previous post was useful.Regards

Comment: It is just a standard Maven war project where you add the MuleXmlBuilderContextListener in web.xml to kick-start Mule. Nothing to it really.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You might want to take a look to the [Embedding Mule in a Java Application or Webapp](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Embedding+Mule+in+a+Java+Application+or+Webapp) manual page, and the [Deploying Mule as a Service to Tomcat](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Deploying+Mule+as+a+Service+to+Tomcat).